# For table cmdb_rel_ci, I want to retrieve unique parent.sys_class_name with count for "type=In Rack::Rack contains"

Tags: servicenow

For table cmdb_rel_ci, I want to retrieve unique parent.sys_class_name with count for "type=In Rack::Rack contains". I am doing practice in out of the box instance.
At table level URL is as below:

[URL](https://YOUR_INSTANCE_ID.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fcmdb_rel_ci_list.do%3Fsysparm_query%3Dtype%253De76b8c7b0a0a0aa70082c9f7c2f9dc64%255EGROUPBYparent.sys_class_name%26sysparm_first_row%3D1%26sysparm_view%3D)

I want to retrieve result from above URL with my below script.

```js
var count = new GlideAggregate('cmdb_rel_ci');
count.addQuery('type','e76b8c7b0a0a0aa70082c9f7c2f9dc64');// sys_id of type In Rack::Rack contains e76b8c7b0a0a0aa70082c9f7c2f9dc64
count.addAggregate('COUNT', 'parent.sys_class_name');
count.query();

while(count.next()){  
  var parentClassName = count.parent.sys_class_name.toString();
  var parentClassNameCount = count.getAggregate('COUNT','parent.sys_class_name');
  gs.log(parentClassName + " : " + parentClassNameCount );
}
```

The issue is I am getting parentClassName empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var parentClassName = count.getValue("parent.sys_class_name")
```

Since it's a `GlideAggregate` query (instead of `GlideRecord`), the query being issued isn't returning all of the fields on the target table. With `GlideRecord`, dot-walking through a reference field (e.g. `parent.sys_class_name`) automatically resolves that referenced record to provide access to its field values. This is made possible by the fact that the driving/original query brought back the value of the `parent` field. This is not happening with `GlideAggregate`. The query in this case basically looks like:

```
SELECT cmdb1.`sys_class_name` AS `parent_sys_class_name`, count(*) 
FROM (cmdb_rel_ci cmdb_rel_ci0  LEFT JOIN cmdb cmdb1 ON cmdb_rel_ci0.`parent` = cmdb1.`sys_id` )  
WHERE cmdb_rel_ci0.`type` = 'e76b8c7b0a0a0aa70082c9f7c2f9dc64' 
GROUP BY cmdb1.`sys_class_name` 
ORDER BY cmdb1.`sys_class_name`
```

So, you actually have access specifically to that dot-walked sys_class_name that's being grouped, but not *through* the dot-walk. The call to `getValue("parent.sys_class_name")` is expectedly resolved to the returned column aliased as `parent_sys_class_name`.

That being said, what you're doing probably should *also work*, based on user expectations, so you've not done anything incorrect here.